# JUnit Test for a servlet

Tags: java, junit

I am not familiar with Junit testing at all. How would I go about creating a junit test for this code? I have already set up the test file.

```
 @WebServlet("/version")
 public class TypeCheck extends HttpServlet {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 987654321;

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        BufferedReader read = null;

        InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/version.txt");

        try {
           read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

           response.getWriter().write(read.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
           if (read != null) { try { read.close(); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the best serialVersionUID by the way. And you'd better refer to testing manuals and ask specific questions here. You question is too broad.

Comment: okay I just don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading the Getting Started section of the JUnit docs:
https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started

Since you're testing a Servlet, you're going to need to use some mocks too, since doGet() has a number of params that it expects that you'll need to pass these to call/test that method.

If you're learning JUnit from scratch, it might be easier to test something simpler, a simple Java class, that doesn't require mocking first to get the hang of the basics, and then move into looking at how to use mock frameworks together with Junit as a next step.